# Problems by deleting rows - AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

The problem I am encountering is that if I have 2 or more rows and then want to delete a single row, it deletes all the rows at the same time. Maybe they are connected or not, strange behaviour.

This problem arised after I added `OrderByPriority` in order to search through the table. If I delete `OrderByPriority` I can delete the rows individually, but then I cannot search... Is there a way I can search through the table and also being able to delete single rows without deleting all the rows at the same time just by deleting a single row.

Open for ideas and inpus.

[Click here for plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/40ktmcGS149rdPHqri2P?p=preview)

Snapshot of a part in index.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Plate Number</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(id, item) in items | orderByPriority | filter:search">
          <td>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code in your question? And maybe a sample of your firebase data (as text, not a screenshot)?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the firebase item `$id` to delete the actual row on firebase

```
ng-click="removeItem(item.$id)"
```

item.$id is generated by firebase and it's unique across all elements; so, you have to pass this $id to delete actual item.